# Foursquare's Layout

Tags: iphone, uitableview, layout

Anyone knows how is structured Foursquare App's layout?

Look this: [Foursquare's App Screenshot](http://timskaggs.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/foursquare_iphone.jpeg)
(the view on the right)

I'm trying to create a similar layout. There is a navigation bar and after? TableView header?
I'm not understanding what is the bar with user's avatar and the others stuff.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't KNOW, so I'm not going to post this as an answer. But it looks like a custom view to me. Surprisingly easy to do, if you have any trouble implementing one ask specific questions. If it scrolls, it's assigned to the UITableView's tableHeader. If not, it's just on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly standard to me.

A UIView, with a UIImageView and 3 UILabels.

Then two UIButtons, and finally..

A UITableView nested in the bottom..

As the other user said, if the top section scrolls when you move the table, the Image, Labels and Buttons are sat inside the TableView Header.

```
            UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] init];

            table.tableHeaderView = UIView including image, labels and buttons
```